# Find the probability function of $Z$

Tags: probability

Let  $X_1,X_2$ be a random variables with geometric distribution with $p$,

let as define $Z:=$max$\{X_1,X_2\}$

> Find the probability function of $Z$

My start:

$$X_1,X_2\sim G(p)$$

Now I need to find $\color{blue}{(1)} P(X_1>X_2),\color{blue}{(2)}P(X_2>X_1),\color{blue}{(3)}P(X_1=X_2)$

$$\color{blue}{(3)}P(X_1=X_2=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$$

$$\color{blue}{(1)}P(X_1<X_2)=\frac{p(1-p)^{X_2-1}-1}{(1-p)-1}$$

$$\color{blue}{(1)}P(X_2<X_1)=\frac{p(1-p)^{X_1-1}-1}{(1-p)-1}$$

> My attempt is correct?

Comment: You cannot still have $X_1$ or $X_2$ on the RHS: the RHS must be a real number, not a random variable. (To help solve the problem: typically, for the maximum of i.i.d. random variables, looking at the cumulative distribution function to characterize the distribution is a good idea.)

Comment: So $X_i$ in the RHS equal to $k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z$ is less or equal than $k$ if and only if both $X_1$ and $X_2$ (assumed independent here -- otherwise the exercise has a much different flavor) are both less or equal than $k$. Looking at the cumulative distribution function, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{align}
F_Z(k) &= \mathbb{P}\{ Z \leq k\} = \mathbb{P}\{ X_1 \leq k\}\cdot \mathbb{P}\{ X_1 \leq k\} \\
&= F_{X_1}(k)\cdot F_{X_2}(k) = (1-(1-p)^k)\cdot (1-(1-p)^k) \\
&= (1-(1-p)^k)^2
\end{align}$$

Now, since $\mathbb{P}\{Z=k\} = F_Z(k) - F_Z(k-1)$ (for $k\geq 1$) and $\mathbb{P}\{Z=0\} = F_Z(0) = 0$, you get
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{Z=k\} &= (1-(1-p)^k)^2 - (1-(1-p)^{k-1})^2
\end{align}$$
(this may simplify a little, but I'm not sure how much.)

Comment: It nicely simplifies to $P(Z=k)=pq^{k-1}(2-q^{k-1}-q^k)=2P_k(1-\frac {P_{k}+P_{k+1}}{2p})\sim 2P_k$. This also strengthens the connection between geometric and exponential distributions.

Answer (score 2):

It may be wiser to calculate the probility $Q(k)=P(X_1\le k\wedge X_2\le k)$ that *both* $X_1$ and $X_2$ take a value no more than $k$. Once you manage to calculate this, $Q(k)-Q(k-1)$ will give you what you want.